# Given a Class Can Roslyn be used to get the graph closure of all required classes?

Tags: c#, roslyn

At time I find that I would like to grab a class and move it to a separate project, however I would end up pulling it's dependencies and so on and so fourth.

Can Roslyn be used to grab the graph closure of a given class?

Comment: This is more difficult than you think it is.  Resharper can show you the dependency graph of a class, but automatically moving every dependent artifact of a class somewhere else is almost certainly not what you actually want.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : Thank you, what is it that I am after then? down the rabbit hole I go!

Comment: What you really want is to group common classes into one or more cohesive libraries with common functionality, and then reference those libraries as needed in your projects.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : That is what I am trying to do! My personal projects develop like that, but I need to pull every thing out piece by piece for refactoring, it is an MVC project with 15 developers!

Comment: You'll need to do it by hand.  I recommend that you obtain a copy of Resharper, if you don't already have one, and use its Dependency Graph functionality to decide which classes you're going to move.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : I have Resharper license, what is the kata for such types of refactoring? What is the refactoring topic that I want to be able to group common classes into one or more cohesive libraries with common functionality, and then reference those libraries as needed in  projects?

Comment: This isn't going to be an automated thing.  You need to look at the dependency graph, decide which classes you're going to move, and copy/paste them to another solution.  Should take you about 15 to 20 minutes, depending on the complexity of the object graph..